# Function keys (Backspace. arrows, delete, etc.) do not work on dynamically generated input field

Tags: jquery

I am creating input elements with JQuery, but i encountered the problem, that function keys like backspace or the arrow keys are not working after triggering the focus() event programatically.
All other keys work fine.

When I click inside the input field manually, the keys start working.

I already spent a few hours on google and stackoverflow, but it seems noone ever had the same problem, so I was not able to solve it yet.

```
function MyFunction(elm)
{ 
  var oldName = elm.html();
  var newTextBox = $("<input type=\"text\">");
  elm.html(newTextBox);
  newTextBox.val(oldName);
  newTextBox.focus();
}
```

[Edit]

A fiddle of my code can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/6rjbyLg2/.
Since the fiddle works just fine, I assume the problem is somewhere else in my code. I am gonna update this post, as soon as I find anything.

Comment: You will have to show us some more code, also if you can create a working example of the problem would be a huge help

Comment: Hi, i have created a fiddle (see edit) but it seems the issue is not the input itself, as the fiddle is working. Unfortunately, I can not post "more" code, as I have no idea yet, which part of the 3k lines could be responsible for this behaviour. But the code above is basically all I do to create the inputs.

Comment: search for keycode for the keys in your program, You might have disabled them somewhere

Answer (score -1):

So instead of `elm.html(newTextBox)` try `elm.append(newTextBox)`. By using `append` this keeps all bound events on the `newTextBox` where as using `html` puts  a plain element in there. Furthermore, once it's been appended, then apply your `on` event binding methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly I already tried to append the textbox, which leads to the same results.

Comment: Did you try binding events after the appending?